# Touchpad stops working under heavy load in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, touchpad

When I boot webserver and it takes all of PC recources rendering it helpless it makes my life even worse, Windows tries to free some RAM (or whatever) and disables my touchpad (or just the scrolling gesture of it) I can navigate using keybard but coursor is totally stuck and shows no life signals whatever I try to do with touchpad.

Is ther an option to add touchpad app or drivers into top priority list that never gets cut by the system?

Running SONY VAIO Fit 15 (8gigs RAM, Windows 8.1 Pro)

Comment: Does this problem happen while in safe mode?

Comment: Nope, normal mode.